# How can I use a macro that is defined from a base template file

Tags: jinja2

I have a structure of a template as follow:

```
"base.jinja2"
{% macro a_macro() %}
   {# Something #}
{%- endmacro %}

{# Something #}
{% include "the_second_template.jinja2" %}

"the_second_template.jinja2"
{{ a_macro() }} {# call a_macro function #}
```

For this context, the statement that call "a_macro" function cannot execute "a_macro" function form "the_second_template.jinja2" file.

So, Is there any way to do that? Or any idea to do the similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs: If the macro was defined in a different template you have to import it first.

Answer (score 1):

```
"the_second_template.jinja2"

{% import "base.jinja2" as html %}

{{ html.a_macro() }} {# call a_macro function #}
```